# npm init saying INVALID_ARG_TYPE

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, init

npm init used to work perfectly fine for me, but now it is showing The "original" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object.

This is how it looks like-

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
npm ERR! The "original" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RONAK ASNANI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-16T21_24_05_114Z-debug.log
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahP5A.png)

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: This does seem odd, I've never seen that before. Honestly my best bet would be to do a reinstall.

Comment: I reinstalled it but the same thing is happening

Comment: If you do `npm -v` what version do you get? Mine is 7.13.0

Comment: It's 7.11.2  on npm -v

Comment: It worked on updating npm ,thanks